# Coefficient in defining Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I don't know why we define below coefficient in Fourier transform?

[image]

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It normalizes the Fourier transform so that the $L^2$ norm of the transformed function is the same as the $L^2$ norm of the original function.

Comment: can you explain more?